# Excel VBA Save multiple sheets from a range to a single PDF

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, pdf

I'm currently working on workbook where in column A:A of worksheet("STAM-Filialen") nearly all the names of the other worksheets are. I want only those worksheets named in column("A:A") in a single PDF. The code I use know makes it a separate file for each worksheet. Is it possible to use a sort of a same code to save it as a single PDF?

```
Dim myCell As Range
Dim lastCell As Long
Dim PathName As String
lastCell = lastRow("STAM-Filialen")
PathName = Range("I10").Value

Worksheets("STAM-Filialen").Activate
For Each myCell In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("STAM-Filialen").Range("A2:A" & lastCell).Cells
    Dim wksName As String
    wksName = myCell.Text
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wksName).Range("A1:P60").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=PathName & "DispoPlan.Filiaal " & wksName & ".PDF"
Next
```

Comment: @RyanWildry You were correct.  Removed answer and comment regarding Union, as it is not allowing combination of sheets.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend moving all the values to a single sheet to print. Then delete this temporary sheet when done.

Here's an example of placing each range from each sheet side by side in a new sheet.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CreateSinglePDF()
    Dim ws As Range: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A4")
    Dim rangeDict As Object: Set rangeDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In ws
        If Not rangeDict.exists(cell.Value) And cell.Value <> "" Then
            rangeDict.Add cell.Value, ThisWorkbook.Sheets(cell.Value).Range("A1:A5")
        End If
    Next

    Dim printsheet As Worksheet
    Set printsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))

    Dim key As Variant
    Dim i As Long: i = 1
    For Each key In rangeDict
        printsheet.Range(printsheet.Cells(1, i), printsheet.Cells(5, i)).Value = rangeDict(key).Value
        i = i + 1
    Next

    printsheet.UsedRange.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="C:\users\ryan\desktop\ExampleFile.pdf"
    printsheet.Delete
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert multiple sheets into single pdf document,

1. first select multiple sheets
2. and use the Activesheet.ExportAsFixedFormat statement.
3. The print range of the page can be set in Page Setup.

### Code

```
   Sub test()
        Dim WB As Workbook
        Dim Ws As Worksheet
        Dim sht As Worksheet
        Dim PathName As String
        Dim vWs() as String '<~~ Variable change
        Dim rngDB As Range, rng As Range
        Dim n As Integer

        Set WB = ThisWorkbook
        Set Ws = WB.Worksheets("STAM-Filialen")

        PathName = Range("I10").Value

        With Ws
            Set rngDB = .Range("a1", .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        End With

        For Each rng In rngDB
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve vWs(1 To n)
            vWs(n) = rng.text '<~~ text
            Set sht = Sheets(rng.Value)
            With sht.PageSetup
                .PrintArea = "a1:p60"
            End With
        Next rng
        Sheets(vWs).Select '<~~ multiple sheets select
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, filename:=PathName & "DispoPlan.Filiaal.PDF"

    End Sub
```

### Worksheets("STAM-Filialen")

[image]

### Specipic Sheets selected

[image]

### Single pdf

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works for what I can view now. The only problem I get is with 1 number, 59, it doesn't find the worksheet(59_. Do you know what could be the problem?

Comment: The problem comes with the part `Set sht = Sheets(rng.Value)`

Comment: @WouterGroeneweg, Check if there are any sheet names in column a that are not in the actual sheet.

Comment: @WouterGroeneweg, If your sheet name is numeric, change to  Set sht = Sheets(rng.text)

Comment: The change helped. What do I have to change the part of `Sheets(vWs).Select` to get it working?

Comment: @WouterGroeneweg, Can you upload your file image so that the sheet tab is visible?

Comment: the update you gave with the `Dim vWs() As String` and `vWs(n) = rng.Text` Helped and now it works. Thank you!